# PayPal how to pass the id to the client

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working on integrating PayPal to my site, however I've got to the point where it requests me to pass the id back to the client.  And I'm not sure how to do this.  Any help would be great.

This is the last JSON code I get from the PayPal servers.  As I'm doing it from the server side code.

```
{
"id":"PAY-5VL741754E714161BLHUWCKY",
"intent":"sale",
"state":"created",
"payer":
{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
},
"transactions":
[{
    "amount":
    {
        "total":"4.00",
        "currency":"USD",
        "details":
        {
            "subtotal":"2.00",
            "tax":"2.00",
            "shipping":"1.00",
            "shipping_discount":"-1.00"
        }
    },
    "description":"The payment transaction description.",
    "custom":"PlayerID",
    "invoice_number":"merchant invoice",
    "item_list":
        {
        "items":
            [{
            "name":"item 1",
            "description":"item 1 description",
            "price":"1.00",
            "currency":"USD",
            "tax":"1.00",
            "quantity":1
            },
            {
            "name":"item 2",
            "description":"item 2 description",
            "price":"1.00",
            "currency":"USD",
            "tax":"1.00",
            "quantity":1
            }]
        },
        "related_resources":
        []
    }],
    "create_time":"2017-10-20T02:36:27Z",
    "links":
    [{
      "href":"h.t.t.p.s.:././.a.p.i...s.andbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5VL741754E714161BLHUWCKY",
        "rel":"self",
        "method":"GET"
    },
    {
        "href":"h.t.t.p.s.:././.w.w.w...s.andbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-3U757031AX945661J",
        "rel":"approval_url",
        "method":"REDIRECT"
    },
    {
      "href":"h.t.t.p.s:././.a.p.i...s.a.ndbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5VL741754E714161BLHUWCKY/execute",
        "rel":"execute",
        "method":"POST"
    }
```

]}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json_decode()` function [*(function docs)*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the JSON information into a multi-dimensional array.

---

The following script will echo out the ID as required (provided `$response` is the JSON-encoded response from the PayPal transaction):

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
echo $data['id'];
```

Comment: yeah I get that, but how do I pass that back to the client so that it can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, and its the following.

```
$response1 = json_decode($response);
$payment_id = $response1->id;
$payment_id = print_r($payment_id, true);

print ("{
     \"id\": \"$payment_id\"
}");
```